# Pygame's arc to be used as a sprite

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I am trying to use the pygame.draw.arc() as a sprite, but its not displaying on the screen. 
I can achieve the same effect by writing same code in the main loop, but once I try to create a sprite, the effect is not being displayed.

(One part in the main-loop can be un-commented to see the desired effect as well.)

Any pointers could be of great help.

```
import pygame
import random
import math


BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 513
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 513
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.color = color
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])

        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        self.center_x = SCREEN_WIDTH/2-15
        self.center_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-15
        # Draw the ellipse, THIS WORKS PERFECTLY
        #pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, color, [0, 0, width, height])

        self.i=0
        #THIS DOESN'T WORK FOR SOME REASON
        pygame.draw.arc(self.image, (0,255,255),(25,25,450,450),0+(self.i*math.pi)/180,math.pi/6 +(self.i*math.pi)/180,10)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.angle = 0
        self.radius = 210
        self.speed = 0.05

    def update(self):
        self.i += self.speed


pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

block = Block(BLACK, 20, 15) 
all_sprites_list.add(block) 

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
i=0
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # 
            done = True  
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites_list.update()

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    #UNCOMMENT TO SEE THE DESIRED EFFECT
    #i= i+1
    #pygame.draw.arc(screen, (0,255,255),(25,25,450,450),0+(i*math.pi)/180,math.pi/6 +(i*math.pi)/180,10)
    pygame.display.flip() 
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You draw the arc outside of the surface.

Here you pass the values `20` and `15` to `Block`:

```
block = Block(BLACK, 20, 15)
```

So you create a `Surface` with the size `20, 15`:

```
self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
```

Then you draw the arc in the area `25,25,450,450`:

```
pygame.draw.arc(self.image, (0,255,255),(25,25,450,450),0+(self.i*math.pi)/180,math.pi/6 +(self.i*math.pi)/180,10)
```

But that area is outside the surface, because it is only 20 pixels wide and 15 pixels high.

The area you passed to `pygame.draw.arc` is relative to `self.image`.

Comment: One more thing, is it fine to write something like this in update() ? or it should be avoided ?
   
 `def update(self):`
        `self.i = self.i + 1`
        `self.image.fill(WHITE)`
        `self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)`
        `pygame.draw.arc(self.image, (0,255,255),(0,0,450,450),0+(self.i*math.pi)/180,math.pi/6 +(self.i*math.pi)/180,10)`

Comment: @Sokio I think that's not a problem. If you have multiple `Block` objects and you observe a serious performance loss, it might be useful to cache the surfaces, but that's another topic.